# Another Method Definition in Constructor call?

Tags: java, constructor

I'm looking at the Hive Opensource Code and came across a weird constructor call:

```
public ResultSet getUDTs(String catalog, String schemaPattern,
  String typeNamePattern, int[] types) throws SQLException {

  return new HiveMetaDataResultSet(
        Arrays.asList("TYPE_CAT", "TYPE_SCHEM", "TYPE_NAME", "CLASS_NAME", "DATA_TYPE"
                , "REMARKS", "BASE_TYPE")
        , Arrays.asList("STRING", "STRING", "STRING", "STRING", "INT", "STRING", "INT")
        , null) {

    public boolean next() throws SQLException {
      return false;
  }
};
```

}

The constructor definition for HiveMetaDataResultSet is to take in three List as parameters.

My question is what does the:

```
public boolean next() throws SQLException {
  return false;
}
```

part do in this case? It is not an anonymous call as an argument, since the 3 arguments are complete by there own and this one comes in the body of the constructor call.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This method is returning an instance of an [**anonymous inner class**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html). Thus, this is a class definition within a method, and a method definition within that class.

The object returned from this method is an instance of a class that is defined right where the method return, and that class is a subclass of `HiveMetaDataResultSet`, with `next()` overriden to the `next` implementation defined right there.

Comment: Thank you for helping me! I figured it out now. The HiveMetaDataResultSet class is an abstract class, so when instantiating it, an actual definition for the empty method signature needs to be provided.